# Comparing the top and bottom row for a case when statement in SQL

Tags: sql, ssms

I have been trying to write this query for a good min and I still can not figure it out on SSMS.

When looking at the Days_Since_Last Visit column I am going to compare the results on the Patient_ID. If there is a null in the initial row of the Days_Since_Last Visit column and the following row there is a number greater than 0 and you compare it to the Patient ID column and the top and the bottom of the row you were comparing the null and the number greater than o are for the same patient, label both rows as Set.

If there is a null and that following row is followed by a 0 and it is for the same patient ID for both rows, then label both rows then label it NO

Anything else is No

I am trying to get the column Test [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwqDU.png)for my outcome.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AS4b.png)

I tried this but it was wrong

```
SELECT  
  *,  
  CASE  
    WHEN Days_Since_Last_Visit IS NULL  
      AND LEAD(Days_Since_Last_Visit) OVER (ORDER BY Patient_ID) > 0  
      AND Patient_ID = LAG(Patient_ID) OVER (ORDER BY Patient_ID)  
      THEN 'Set'  
    WHEN Days_Since_Last_Visit IS NULL  
      AND LEAD(Days_Since_Last_Visit) OVER (ORDER BY Patient_ID) = 0  
      AND Patient_ID = LAG(Patient_ID) OVER (ORDER BY Patient_ID)  
      THEN 'NO'  
    ELSE 'no'  
  END AS Label  
FROM #Test;
```

Comment: SSMS is just an IDE-like application. What RDBMS are you using? You should tag that, not the GUI. Tagging [[tag:SSMS]] is like tagging [[tag:vscode]] for your programming language.

Comment: Your two images seem to show the same results in the "Test" column, so it's not entirely clear what your expected output is...

Answer (score 0):

Setting up some sample data matching what you've posted:

```
create table #data
(
    CONTACT_DATE date,
    Encounter_ID int,
    Patient_ID int,
    CPT_CODE nvarchar(5),
    Days_Since_Last_Visit int
)

insert into #data values
('2022-08-11',1111,1,'D0140',NULL),
('2022-09-16',2222,1,'D0140',36),
('2022-04-18',3333,2,'D0140',NULL),
('2022-09-26',4444,2,'D0140',161),
('2022-11-22',5555,3,'D0150',NULL),
('2022-04-11',55555,4,'D0140',NULL),
('2022-05-19',66666,4,'D0140',38),
('2021-12-06',77777,5,'D0140',NULL),
('2022-04-25',88888,5,'D0140',140),
('2023-04-25',99999,6,'D0150',NULL),
('2023-04-25',101010,6,'D0150',0)
```

You can use `PARTITION BY` in your `OVER` clause to remove the need for matching `Patient_ID` values:

```
select
    *,
    case when Days_Since_Last_Visit is null and lead(Days_Since_Last_Visit) over (partition by Patient_ID order by CONTACT_DATE) > 0
        then 'Set'
        else 'No'
    end as [Label]
from #data
```

This returns the results I *think* you want (although as per my comment, it's not clear because the screenshots of your actual and desired output are the same):

```
+--------------+--------------+------------+----------+-----------------------+-------+
| CONTACT_DATE | Encounter_ID | Patient_ID | CPT_CODE | Days_Since_Last_Visit | Label |
+--------------+--------------+------------+----------+-----------------------+-------+
| 2022-08-11   |         1111 |          1 | D0140    | NULL                  | Set   |
| 2022-09-16   |         2222 |          1 | D0140    | 36                    | No    |
| 2022-04-18   |         3333 |          2 | D0140    | NULL                  | Set   |
| 2022-09-26   |         4444 |          2 | D0140    | 161                   | No    |
| 2022-11-22   |         5555 |          3 | D0150    | NULL                  | No    |
| 2022-04-11   |        55555 |          4 | D0140    | NULL                  | Set   |
| 2022-05-19   |        66666 |          4 | D0140    | 38                    | No    |
| 2021-12-06   |        77777 |          5 | D0140    | NULL                  | Set   |
| 2022-04-25   |        88888 |          5 | D0140    | 140                   | No    |
| 2023-04-25   |        99999 |          6 | D0150    | NULL                  | No    |
| 2023-04-25   |       101010 |          6 | D0150    | 0                     | No    |
+--------------+--------------+------------+----------+-----------------------+-------+
```

If you actually want a different output value in the "Test" column to differentiate between rows which are "No" because of a non-zero numeric value in `Days_Since Last_Visit` and those which are "No" because they have a NULL value in `Days_Since Last_Visit`, but no corresponding non-zero numeric value for the same `Patient_ID`, then you'll need to expand the `CASE` statement accordingly.